# Installing Boost on Unix...can't unzip boost library

Tags: unix, boost, installation

I am trying to install Boost on an unix cluster machine following the [Boost instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)

I downloaded boost_1_43_0.tar.bz2 and was then instructed to execute the following command: 
tar --bzip2 -xf /path/to/boost_1_43_0.tar.bz2

However it didn't work and this is the output I get:

> tar --bzip2 -xf
>   /path/to/boost_1_43_0.tar.bz2
>
> tar: /path/to/boost_1_43_0.tar.bz2:
>   Cannot open: No such file or directory
>
> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting
>   now
>
> tar: Child returned status 2
>
> tar: Error exit delayed from previous
>   errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't literally write `/path/to/boost_1_43_0.tar.bz2`.

If the archive is in the current directory, you write `./boost_1_43_0.tar.bz2`, for instance.  Or if you saved it in the `/tmp` directory, the command would be `tar --bzip2 -xf /tmp/boost_1_43_0.tar.bz2`.

Instructions that use `/path/to/some/file` to indicate that you need to use your own path are pretty common.  You'll need to be careful about reading the commands before you execute them in the future, too.

Answer (score 1):

By `/path/to/boost_1_43_0.tar.bz2` they mean the path to the downloaded file, wherever you happened to save it on your machine.  So if you downloaded it in /home/Elpezmuerto, the path would be `/home/Elpezmuerto/boost_1_43_0.tar.bz2`.